# How to overcome a precision error in Python when summing a list of floating point numbers?

Tags: python, math, precision

In Python3, `0.35 * 10` does not show the same result as summing a list of 10 numbers `0.35`.

```
Python 3.8.1 (v3.8.1:1b293b6006, Dec 18 2019, 14:08:53) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.35 * 10
3.5
>>> a = [0.35 for i in range(0, 10)]
>>> sum(a)
3.5000000000000004
```

Is it possible to overcome this precision error with Python3 alone? By that I mean without using libraries like numpy.

Comment: FYI even though 0.35 is parsed to a float whose exact value is 0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, multiplying it by 10 yields exactly 3.5, funny how that works out.

Comment: The error is due to how floating point is implemented and is not unique to Python.  See [Is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Possibly better dupe target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/is-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available

Comment: This should be re-opened. Note, that in Python 3.12, the `sum` algorithm changed so that `sum(a) == 3.5` will return `True`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can understand why the canonical floating point math question doesn't really answer this one, but how is it not a dupe of the one I linked in the earlier comment?

Comment: @JaredSmith because the OP doesn't want arbitrary precision, they want improved accuracy of floating point sums, which is possible.

Comment: @harold anything ending in .5 can be an exact number in binary.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48374522/5987 for an example that confused me.

Comment: Note: if you only want 2-digit decimal numbers, then you could also work with fixed-point numbers instead of floating-point numbers.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. @juanpa.arrivillaga posted a working solution so I'm picking that as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, one way to do this that is available on older versions of Python is to use `math.fsum`, if you are working with a list of `float` objects. It slower than `sum`, but it is fairly accurate, so, e.g. with python 3.8:

```
(py38) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ python
Python 3.8.18 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec 23 2023, 17:23:49)
[Clang 15.0.7 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [0.35 for i in range(0, 10)]
>>> sum(a)
3.5000000000000004
>>> sum(a) == 0.35*10
False
```

However,

```
>>> import math
>>> math.fsum(a)
3.5
>>> math.fsum(a) == 0.35*10
True
```

Please read the caveats in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum).

Also, if you can just upgrade to CPython 3.12, [they actually improved the built-in `sum`](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100425) function:

```
(py312) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ python
Python 3.12.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec 23 2023, 08:05:03) [Clang 16.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [0.35 for i in range(0, 10)]
>>> sum(a)
3.5
>>> sum(a) == 0.35*10
True
```

From what I understand, `numpy.sum` (sometimes but not always) uses partial pairwise summation.

In Python 3.12, when you work with floats, `sum` will use Arnold Neumaier's variant of compensated summation (a la Kahan).

`math.fsum` is apparently even more precise, but slow.

Comment: I have to wonder what's going on with the Python 3.12 example there. I can see that `sum` could detect duplicates and therefore deduce that the sum is 10 times 0.35, but I don't see how `sum` could get exactly 3.5, because 0.35 isn't exactly representable as a base 2 float while 3.5 is. Is the output from `sum(a)` actually exactly 3.5? (What is `sum(a) - 3.5`?) If so maybe you can say briefly how `sum` gets that result.

Comment: @RobertDodier it is simply using an algorithm that is more accurate. I [linked to the github discussion where the implementer writes about the algorithm that was chosen](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100425)